# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'. in react native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-pdf

I installed react-native-pdf and now when I run "npx react-native run-android", it fails with the following:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
```

Can anyone help me use the package react-native-pdf?

[image: ive]

Answer (score 65):

I had the same issue and i resolved it by adding the following to android/app/build.gradle

```
android {

packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
}

/** rest of your code here **/
```

}

Comment: does anyone know why do we need to do this? i really dont like gradle tool, there is no explanation...

Comment: Gives the impression that including the react native pdf reader library somehow introduces other versions of these files and you're telling the compiler which ones to look at or something?

Comment: This feels like a hack...

Answer (score 13):

add this to your `app/build.gradle`

```
android {
   // yout existing code
   packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/libfbjni.so'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Open the project in Android Studio android and clean the project
`Build -> Clean Project`

Comment: Thanks.. it was just a stale environment. Running flutter -clean worked.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to "/android/app/build.gradle"

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
      pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
  }
  /** .... **/
}
```

So run this on the terminal

```
$ cd android/
$ ./gradlew cleanBuildCache
$ cd ..
$ sudo npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

For us, it was caused by `react-native-pdf`.

So either, eject the project and update `build.gradle` same as other answers say or, get rid of it if not used or you may replace it with `rn-pdf-reader-js`

Comment: Which solution did you go with? Had you updated your Gradle file if yes? what changes were needed exactly?

Comment: We used `rn-pdf-reader-js`. It's much more better

Comment: `rn-pdf-reader-js` is only available for expo projects; if you're running a CRA build you can't use it it seems

Answer (score 0):

For me its gradle cache issue,
I fixed it by running running the following command in the project's root directory:

```
cd android
```

and after

```
./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score -1):

i changed minSdkVersion to 21 in "android/app/build.gradle".

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.custom_epub_view"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

android build.gradle file under **allprojects** add following

```
allprojects {
   configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
   force 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.65.2' //select Version you used
   }
}
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35215#issuecomment-1304878829