# I can't run my flutter app. I always get an erro

Tags: flutter, dart

So, when I run `flutter run` for android I always get an error. This is the error that's giving me

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Multiple build operations failed.
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 17s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             79.4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

But when I run `flutter doctor`, there's no problem

[image]

I tried so many things, before I post here on stockoverflow. I've research the error, but the solutions I found it's not working

Comment: You can try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64116311/4373661

Comment: it's not working mate for me:(

Comment: this is very general description of what is going wrong, what libs are you using etc. you should open project as an android project and try to fix it there.

Comment: well, what I'm trying to do is making it cross platform, so I'm testing it on android

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/62876049/10448036

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: yes I've tried that